# Is this a valid supernetting range for OSPF range command?

Tags: routing, subnet, network, ospf

Is it a right way to supernet/range in OSPF for the following network address?

```
area 0.0.0.x 10.128.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

How `10.128.0.0` can have a subnet of `255.255.255.0`, e.g. `/24`?

Is this a right thing to do?

I thought the right subnet should be `255.255.0.0`, e.g. `/16`?

Am I correct on this?

Comment: Basically, my question is about supernetting , is it correct to supernet the network of 10.128.0.0 with a subnet of 24? Shouldn't that be a subnet of 16?

Comment: A supernet is combining two or more networks into a smaller prefix. If you have If you have some larger prefixes, e.g. `/25`, you can combine them to a supernet with any smaller prefix, e.g. `/22`. I think you need to study the excellent answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499).

Comment: To avoid confusion, better enable OSPF per interface.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what your underlying network sizes are, you can aggregate them to a prefix smaller than what you started with. For example, if you have these networks:

- `10.128.0.0/30`
- `10.128.0.4/30`
- `10.128.0.8/29`
- `10.128.0.16/29`
- `10.128.0.24/29`

You can aggregate them into `10.128.0.0/27`.

---

Don't get hung up on the octets, which are simply to make it easier for humans to read. You need to do IP manipulation in binary.